# Is it ok to ask such a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question in my mind, I want convert a problem to logic order 2 representation, but I can't, Also I don't know is it good to ask it in cstheory or not? I don't know can I say it's research level or not (problem is pretty hard but converting to logic 2 I can't say is hard or not), no one around me is expert in logic to help me, and I need to read some book, but If someone expert answer me my works will be done very faster, because main part of my problem is not related to logic.

Comment: Depending on the problem, it could well be relevant.

Comment: @Kaveh understanding my problem is not easy for mathematical people but good suggestion. It doesn't have such a rule like CS?

Comment: @Saeed, no, they don't restrict the scope to research level, but read their FAQ for more information (in fact it was created after MO which is research level only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Math.SE if you are not sure.

If it doesn't get answered there and based on the comments then you can decide whether it is suitable for cstheory or not.